# how to add gerrit server hook when ever a patch get submitted (patchset-created)

Tags: git, bash, shell, gerrit

I want to add a hook in my gerrit server that every time a patch will be submitted the commit hash of the patch will be printed to a temporary file.
I've added a script tcalled patchset-created under {gerrit project folder}/hooks, and also changed its mode to be fully opened (I used the mask of 777 just to be sure), but it appears that the script does not execute when I upload a patch...

Is there a step which I'm missing? I didn't found any "step by step" documentation for it which describes it clearly enough.

Does some one have an example of how that should be done?

Comment: It's not unusual for programs to refuse to run programs that are world writable, or refuse to use sensitive files that are readable by anyone but the owner. In this case the write bit is completely irrelevant so by setting the filemode to 0777 rather than 0755 or 0555 you're theoretically _decreasing_ the chances of getting it to work. That said I don't think Gerrit cares about this. Going back to your problem, is there anything useful in any of the Gerrit logs?

Comment: Looking at the gerrit logs it seems that there is no indication those scripts were written

Comment: Which scripts were not written? What's in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you missed to add the eXecutable bit with

```
chmod +x script
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already changed this to 777 just to be sure, but it didn't helped

Comment: The hooks work for us (in Gerrit 2.9.2). Could you post a `ls -la` of the `hooks/` directory in your Gerrit installation? Usually, the `logs/error_log` contains the output of the hooks that are executed.